# How to disable pager in git only for diff with name-only option?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config

I need `git diff` using a pager while `git diff --name-only` not.

Have tried `git config --global pager.diff.name-only false` and not working.

The desired behavior is like `git --no-pager diff --name-only`. But I don't want to type `--no-pager` every time.

Is there any config or alias could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an alias:

```
[alias]
    ndiff = !git --no-pager diff --name-only
```

and then run `git ndiff` instead of `git diff --name-only`.  Or, leave the `--no-pager` part out of the alias and run `git ndiff --name-only`, with `ndiff` standing for no-pager-diff.

Or, instead of `git diff`, you can run `git diff-tree` or `git diff-files` or `git diff-index`.  These three commands are the *plumbing command* back-ends that `git diff` uses for (most of) its various modes of operation.  None of these use a pager, and most of them require additional options (e.g., `-r`) to be used the same way `git diff` would run them, but they do exist and are the right way to write *scripts*.  For your own aliases, there is no need to use the plumbing commands; your own alias can just invoke `git --no-pager diff <options>`.

Comment: Guess have to accept there is no silver bullet for this need. Thank you for sharing `diff-tree` and `diff-files`, they are very useful in some situations. I'll use the alias for now, though sad to discover my shell can't auto-complete branch or commit for `git ndiff`...